# prevent right click on dynamically added images

Tags: jquery, image, contextmenu, right-click

I want to disable right clicks on any images.

This works fine, but only for the static images.

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(
    return false;
});
```

How can I prevent right clicking on images which are added dynamically?

Comment: `$(document).on("contextmenu","img",function(){ return false;});`

Comment: Generally, it's a bad idea to add an answer as a part of the question. I've added that comment as an answer since it solved your issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with a delegated event:

```
$(document).on("contextmenu","img",function(){ return false;});
```

Comment: @Urbycoz well, it didn't take a lot of effort to write nor is it a case that it's extremely useful and there are no duplicates on SO. There are better candidates for upvoting.